# What happens when Bagging does not have a majority vote?

Tags: machine-learning, ensemble-learning, bagging

I have a question regarding the bagging technique used in ensemble learning.

Let's assume I have 6 classifiers which could classify a response variable which has 3 finite categories(`type1,type2,type3`).

In prediction,

two of them classify it as `type1`
two of them classify it as `type2`
two of them classify it as `type3`

So there is no majority vote in this case. What does my ensemble classifier do now?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you use the model and is essentially a design choice. Below I describe how I would proceed, but there is no "standard" for this, so opinions will vary.

Usually you would choose cutoffs per class at some fraction of votes to assign the associated class label. Standard majority voting implies the cutoff is at 0.5, which in this case means your ensemble doesn't assign any label, but it may well be a different cutoff (cfr. ROC curves for example) and in fact the cutoff could even vary across classes.

While not getting a predicted label may seem bad at first, it's actually desirable behavior: you only get labels when the model's confidence is larger than a certain threshold. On the flipside, it's also perfectly possible for a model to assign multiple labels to a single instance, if the cutoffs of different labels are exceeded.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph: a technique that can tell you "d) None of the Above" is valuable, and too many people are satisfied with techniques that give a confident answer even when it's not much more than a random guess. This kind of answer is a win-win because it's a single classification so it's easy to handle downstream. The flip side -- multiple labels -- is harder to work with downstream, but also valuable.